# Delete grandchild and child when entity is deleted

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a Application_Product entity with id as applicationProductId. Credit_Card is the child of Application_Product with id same as Application_Product i.e. applicationProductId (One to One) relationship. Children of Credit_Card is named as Supplimentary_Card with id supplimentaryCardId and foriengn key as applicationProductId of Credit_Card Entity. Cascade, orphan removal is implimented at entity level hence deleting Application_Product should delete Supplimentary_Card . But is not happening. why?

Comment: Can you add some sample code ..... that would help .... What exception you are getting exactly ....

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__supplimen__APPLI__2D536BE9". The conflict occurred in database "COB_APP_DEV", table "dbo.supplimentary_card_data", column 'APPLICATION_PRODUCT_ID'.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the relevant @OneToOne/@OneToMany/@ManyToMany annotations the following property:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

This should ensure all children and grandchildren are removed when the parent is deleted.